# How to get map without subscribe functionality?

Tags: gun

I would like to retrieve all items from a set.

**e.g.** `get("mylist").map().once())`

But I don't want the inherent subscribe functionality of map i.e. I don't want to be notified when a new item is added to the list. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

`.get('mylist').once().map().once()`

There are explanations of each combination you can do in the [documentation](https://gun.eco/docs/API#map).

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks for your reply! Sadly that doesn't work  My callback in the last once() still gets called if a new item is added to my list. The only solution I've found is: `.get('mylist').load()`

Comment: Oh, odd, this seems like a bug then. Could you add it to GitHub issues with sample code to run, that fails?

Comment: Good news, in extracting out the sample code I couldn't reproduce the issue outside of my codebase. I've done some further investigation and .get('mylist').once().map().once() is working as stated! I haven't figured out exactly what's causing the problem within my code....but I will! Thanks again.